# FM transmitter not giving the intended output of 88MHz to 108MHz

Tags: transmitter, frequency-modulation, multisim

I am trying to build an FM transmitter that outputs 88MHz to 108MHz range using Multisim, but the circuit I constructed gives a lower voltage and lower frequency at the output according to the transmitter:

[image: Schematic]

Antenna, (transmitter output):

[image: Output of transmitter, ie antenna]

Input AC voltage (simulate microphone):

[image: Mic]

Two (input and output) signals overlayed:

[image: overlayed signal]

Comment: what produces a sound frequency of 100 MHz?

Comment: It was just to test

Comment: Well, test with something plausible.

Comment: why are you using an audio input that is not in the audio range?

Comment: I dont see any RF design specs or useful results

Comment: Are you sure about wiring R5-C4? The first stage is BF amplifier, second "oscillator"-"mixer", third "power amplifier". So, with nothing injected at input ... it should already "work" (2nd and 3rd stages) ... if components are well "chosen". Be aware that simulating such a thing is "long". Generally, the simulation starts with the last stage (injection of the signal at high frequency, on Q3 base through a 1pF)... AC analysis (88meg-108meg), because it is a "linear" stage.

Answer (score 1):

If you constructed the circuit on a solderless breadboard then all the stray capacitance between the rows of contacts and wires all over the place prevents anything working as high as 100MHz. My FM transmitter circuit is similar to yours but it works perfectly. Use a soldered compact stripboard circuit like this:

[image: FM tx]

Answer (score 0):

Be careful about **laws** specifications!

Here is the third stage ... Antenna characteristics not "used"!
AC Analysis for chosing L and C (88 -> 108 MHz)

[image]

TRAN Analysis with one frequency ...

[image]

Added stage 2, oscillator ... with some modifications for "wave purity"...

[image]

The modulator is up to you ...